# Reading function pointer from file in Fortran

Tags: function, fortran

I am trying to externally specify which function should be called. In the following code, `getEnvelope` is called with the chosen envelope `gaussian`. I would however want to read from a file which specific envelope is used rather than coding `env => gaussian`.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there another preferred way?

```
module laser
  implicit none

  abstract interface
    double precision function envelope(t, tau) result(f)
      double precision, intent(in) :: t, tau
    end function envelope
  end interface

  contains

   double precision function getEnvelope(env, t, tau) result(f)
     procedure(envelope) :: env
     double precision, intent(in) :: t, tau
     f = env(t, tau)
   end function getEnvelope

   double precision function gaussian(t, tau) result(f)
     double precision, intent(in) :: t, tau
     f = exp(-2.d0*log(2.d0)*(t/tau)**2.d0)
   end function gaussian

end module laser

program main
  use laser
  implicit none
  procedure(envelope), pointer :: env
  double precision :: f
  double precision :: t, tau

  env => gaussian

  t = 1.d0
  tau = 200.d0
  f = getEnvelope(env, t, tau)
end program main
```

Comment: Well you could always read the configuration file, parse it and then have `if (conf="gaussian") then env => gaussian` or something similar. I doubt you can use a namelist.

Comment: What @VladimirF suggests.  I suppose you could provide `gaussian` as a command-line argument to the program but that still requires an `if` construct 'parsing' a string.